# aws api gateway endpoint is not public

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

deal tribute,
I built an api endpoint in AWS and set it to public

```
Authorization : NONE  
Request Validator : NONE  
API Key Required : false
```

however, when I try to call the get method, I get this error message

```
[adel@localhost ~]$ curl -sSX GET https://********.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testmovies
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

What shoul I do to make this link publicly available?
thanks in advance

Comment: have you deployed it on any stage? In api gateway there is a tab as Stages where you need to create a stage like dev, prod, etc so that you can deploy your api on it. Once you deploy you will get once universally accessible URL for your API

Comment: that s what i did ... but does not work :(

Comment: it works :) thanks